# CustomJsonConverter to deserialize JSON with one field that could be multiple custom objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am communicating with an API, on various endpoints.  All responses have some shared fields in `meta`, and then a `data` object that can contain any number of custom objects.

A few examples: 
1) A payload returning `data` containing `accounts[]`

```
{
"meta": {
    "timestamp": "2017-07-14T12:59:34-04:00",
    "code": 200
},
"data": {
    "accounts": [
        {
            "address": "Main Street",
            "country": "US",
            "email": "1@23.com",
            "city": "MyTown",
            "accountName": "MyAccount",
            "account": 123456,
            "contact": ""
        }
    ]
}
}
```

2) A payload returning `data` containing `shipments[]`

```
{
"meta": {
    "timestamp": "2017-07-14T13:46:42-04:00",
    "code": 400
},
"data": {
    "shipments": [
        {
            "distributionCenter": "123",
            "packages": [
                {
                    "packageDetails": {},
                    "consigneeAddress": {},
                    "errors": [
                        {
                            "errorCode": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
                            "errorId": 0,
                            "errorMessage": "INVALID_LOGIN"
                        }
                    ],
            ],
            "status": {
                "timestamp": "2017-07-14T13:46:42-0400",
                "numAccepted": 0,
                "numRejected": 1,
                "code": "ERROR"
            },
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I need to have access to `shipments[]` when I hit the `shipments` endpoint, the same with `accounts[]` when hitting `accounts` endpoint.  So that `data.accounts[0].email` is accessible.

The hack way of doing this seems to be creating a `Data` class that has all possible object types, so when serialization/deserialization happens, those not present are just null.

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Account[] accounts { get; set; }
    public Shipment[] shipments { get; set; }
}
```

But I am wondering if there is a way to do this with a Newtonsoft JSON custom JsonConverter. Sa `Data` class looks like:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DataConverter))]
public class Data
{
    \\not sure what to put here...
}
```

Any input on how to get ReadJson to recognize custom objects? Or on other json.net ways of accomplishing this?

```
class DataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Data));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value.GetType() == Shipment)  
        /// this throws error "not valid type in this context"


        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *I am wondering if there is a way to do this with a custom JsonConverter* - what do you want your `Data` type to look like?  Where are you applying the converter?

Comment: Don't have a vision for what `Data` would look like - would just prefer to not have to `{get; set;}` for every possible object type (only gave two examples about, but I'm working with 6+ object types that `data` could contain).  Added sample of where I'd apply converter above

Comment: Doesn't API has documentation on what object type it returns in data when you hit respective endpoint? It must expose that information.

Comment: Yes, it has documentation. But because it's a json response (as opposed to xml) they don't surface it programmatically.  I could write 6 separate classes that are all wrapped individually with identical `meta` and `data` structures, but it would be repeating a lot of code.  Would like to avoid repetition if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would remodel classes to serve different `data` types. To start with I would just have a generic `ApiResponse<T>` as below:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> where T : class {
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class AccountData {
    public Account[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentData {
    public Shipment[] Shipments { get; set; }
}
```

> Don't have a vision for what Data would look like

When you hit a particular end-point you know what API is going to return. IF you ask for accounts it won't give you shipments or something else and vice-versa. Please check API documentation, if available.

Further you can simply create a generic API request method to ask for different kind of Data viz, AccountData, ShipmentData etc.

```
ApiResponse<T> MakeApiRequest<T>(string apiUrl) where T : class {
    // Call API the way you want and get JSON response
    var jsonResponse = "{ \"data\": { \"accounts\": [ { \"address\": \"Main Street\" } ] } }"; // Example data hard-coded
    // Desrialize JSON response into ApiResponse<T>
    var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse, typeof(ApiResponse<T>)) as ApiResponse<T>;
    return apiResponse;
}
```

And call the endpoints using this method:

```
var accountApiResponse = MakeApiRequest<AccountData>("<accounts_api_url>");
var shipmentApiResponse = MakeApiRequest<ShipmentData>("<shipments_api_url>");
```

Comment: Bonus points for generic api request method.  Hadn't gotten that far in my thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move any specific data to subclasses like this:

```
public class AccountData
{
    public Account[] accounts { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentData
{
    public Shipment[] shipments { get; set; }
}
```

From there you move can go from using one response class to one abstract that is your root with common data and two concrete classes with specific information like the following:

```
public abstract class ApiResponse
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}

public class AccountApiResponse : ApiResponse
{
    public AccountData data { get; set; }
}

public class ShipmentApiResponse : ApiResponse
{
    public ShipmentData data { get; set; }
}
```

From there when you make a call to the account endpoint you can retrieve your data with:

```
var accountResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountApiResponse>(json);
```

And for shipments:

```
var shipmentResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShipmentApiResponse>(json);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

what if you make your Data class just an array of objects

```
public class Data
{
    public object[] ResponsePayload {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Using json.net to deserialize, this would cause issues because the property name (`ResponsePayload`) above does not match any fieldname in the json.  Usin `[JsonProperty("shipments")]` for one of the mappings works, but you can only put one `JsonProperty` per field.  I am dealing with 6+ objects, each with their own name, so this approach won't work in this situation

Comment: your json response wont have the field "Shipment" or "Account" in it, but all of those objects could be stored in an array of objects. But you are saying you need to have the json response key that points to the data must be different depending on the data type?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly from your `HttpClient`:

```
var myResponsePayload = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<MyTypeHere>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When you hit your API, they'll come in in that format. Just make sure the properties you want to set in your class line up with what's in the JSON.

If you're not hitting a web service, and reading from a file or a DB instead, I'd recommend  [Newtonsoft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), a widely used NuGet package for json deserialization.

You might end up with something like this:

```
var results = _serializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<MyBingyMathob>>(reader);
```

This will work as long as the class you serialize into has publicly accessible properties with public setters. If you don't want all the data, then missing fields will be dropped.

Comment: The custom converter outlined above is a built-in part of Json.Net (aka Newtonsoft Json).  So trying to go that route.